# Add column and values to CSV or Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Brand new to Python and programming. I have a function that extracts a file creation date from .csv files (the date is included the file naming convention):

```
def get_filename_dates(self):
    """Extract date from filename and place it into a list"""

    for filename in self.file_list:
        try:
            date = re.search("([0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2})",
                         filename).group(0)
            self.file_dates.append(date)
            self.file_dates.sort()
        except AttributeError:
            print("The following files have naming issues that prevented "
                  "date extraction:")
            print(f"\t{filename}")

    return self.file_dates
```

The data within these files are brought into a DataFrame:

```
def create_df(self):
    """Create DataFrame from list of files"""
    for i in range(0, len(self.file_dates)):
        self.agg_data = pd.read_csv(self.file_list[i])
        self.agg_data.insert(9, 'trade_date', self.file_dates[i],
                                 allow_duplicates=False)

    return self.agg_data
```

As each file in file_list is worked with, I need to insert its corresponding date into a new column (trade_date).

As written here, the value of the last index in the list returned by get_filename_dates() is duplicated into every row of the trade_date column. -- presumably because read_csv() opens and closes each file before the next line.

My questions:

- Is there an advantage to inserting data into the csv file using with open() vs. trying to match each file and corresponding date while iterating through files to create the DataFrame?
- If there is no advantage to with open(), is there a different Pandas method that would allow me to manipulate the data as the DataFrame is created? In addition to the data insertion, there's other clean-up that I need to do. As it stands, I wrote a separate function for the clean-up; it's not complex and would be great to run everything in this one function, if possible.

Hope this makes sense -- thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could grab each csv as an intermediate dataframe, do whatever cleaning you need to do, and use pd.concat() to concatenate them all together as you go. Something like this:

```
def create_df(self):
    self.agg_data = pd.DataFrame()

    """Create DataFrame from list of files"""
    for i, date in enumerate(self.file_dates):
        df_part = pd.read_csv(self.file_list[i])
        df_part['trade_date'] = date

        # --- Any other individual file level cleanup here ---

        self.agg_data = pd.concat([self.agg_data, df_part], axis=0)

    # --- Any aggregate-level cleanup here
    return self.agg_data
```

It makes sense to do as much of the preprocessing/cleanup as possible on the aggregated level as you can.

I also went to the liberty of converting the for-loop to use the more pythonic `enumerate`

Comment: Thank you -- this works well, and thanks also for the tip towards enumerate.